# how to convert the enter key to tab key primefaces

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

I have a form with some controls: inputText, autoComplete, selectBooleanCheckbox, selectOneMenu, and others, and I need to use the enter key like tab key, just work it on inputText controls, but in the autoComplete, selectBooleanCheckbox, selectOneMenu doesn´t work.

thanks for the help

Comment: Can you show the code that is converting enter key to tab key?